# Centering figure from GeoGebra

Tags: horizontal-alignment, geogebra

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}  

\usepackage{geometry}% For the margins.  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\newgeometry{  
    top=1in,  
    bottom=1in,  
    outer=1in,  
    inner=1in,  
}

\usepackage{setspace}%Spacing between entries in array.  
\doublespacing% Self explanatory.  
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}  
%\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-10pt}  
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}%for the appendix  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}  
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}%plots,pics, drawings, etc.  
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}%For 3-D plots  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}% For fancy "F"  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\usepackage{float}  
%\usepackage{tikzpicture}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{gensymb}% for degree symbol.  
%\usepackage{pgfplots}%For coordinate plane  
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}  
\usepackage{cancel}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{polynom}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{fouriernc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Shorten Section/Chapter titles in the headers of pages.  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\usepackage{listing}  
\usepackage{qtree}% For drawing trees.  
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree,pstricks-add}%This might be better.df  
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}%Space between paragraphs.  

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]  
\begin{center}%\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle   45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1]%line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle   45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1  
\clip(-4,-1.6) rectangle (5.5,1.6);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely  dotted] (0.,0.)-- (2.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (0.,0.)-- (1.,1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (0.,0.)-- (1.,-1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (1.,1.)-- (2.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (1.,-1.)-- (2.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (2.,0.)-- (3.,1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (2.,0.)-- (3.,-1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (2.,0.)-- (4.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (3.,1.)-- (4.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (3.,-1.)-- (4.,0.);  
\begin{scriptsize}  
\draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large A};  
\draw[fill=black] (1,1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large B};  
\draw[fill=black] (1,-1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=-0.4cm] {\large C};  
\draw [fill=black] (2.,0.) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large D};  
\draw [fill=black] (4.,0.) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large E};  
\draw[fill=black] (3,-1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=-0.4cm] {\large F};  
\draw[fill=black] (3,1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large G};  
\end{scriptsize}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{Example of a graph with open and closed edges.} \label{1}  
\end{center}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What do I need to do so that my figure that I got from GeoGebra is centered in my paper?

Comment: You already centered it (please revert your commentary and use `\centering` instead of `center` again). But maybe you also want vertical centering, so please specify your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output delivered by GeoGebra always contains a `\clip` instruction that most of the times is wrong.

Here's the output with the `\clip` line commented out:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle   45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1]%line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle   45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1  
%\clip(-4,-1.6) rectangle (5.5,1.6);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely  dotted] (0.,0.)-- (2.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (0.,0.)-- (1.,1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (0.,0.)-- (1.,-1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (1.,1.)-- (2.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (1.,-1.)-- (2.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (2.,0.)-- (3.,1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (2.,0.)-- (3.,-1.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (2.,0.)-- (4.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (3.,1.)-- (4.,0.);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (3.,-1.)-- (4.,0.);  
\begin{scriptsize}  
\draw [fill=black] (0.,0.) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large A};  
\draw[fill=black] (1,1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large B};  
\draw[fill=black] (1,-1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=-0.4cm] {\large C};  
\draw [fill=black] (2.,0.) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large D};  
\draw [fill=black] (4.,0.) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large E};  
\draw[fill=black] (3,-1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=-0.4cm] {\large F};  
\draw[fill=black] (3,1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm] {\large G};  
\end{scriptsize}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Here's what I get when the `%` before `\clip` is removed:

[image]

The code should be polished anyway. For instance the `scriptsize` environment is hilarious. I'd also remove the `\large` commands and streamline some constructions.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
  >=triangle 45,
  x=1.0cm,
  y=1.0cm,
  scale=1
]
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely  dotted] (0,0)-- (2,0);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (0,0)-- (1,1);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (0,0)-- (1,-1);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (1,1)-- (2,0);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (1,-1)-- (2,0);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (2,0)-- (3,1);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (2,0)-- (3,-1);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (2,0)-- (4,0);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm] (3,1)-- (4,0);  
\draw [line width=0.35mm, loosely dotted] (3,-1)-- (4,0);  
\fill (0,0)  circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm]  {A};  
\fill (1,1)  circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm]  {B};  
\fill (1,-1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=-0.4cm] {C};  
\fill (2,0)  circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm]  {D};  
\fill (4,0)  circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm]  {E};  
\fill (3,-1) circle (2pt) node[yshift=-0.4cm] {F};  
\fill (3,1)  circle (2pt) node[yshift=0.4cm]  {G};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I really didn't want to touch this code because I don't want to have to redo it and I'm still not proficient in Latex. You'll genuinely lifted my mood.:D